# Exact string match str.count(), pandas python

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy

Counting the column contents for each category, have a set of categories

1. Male-Cat,
2. Female-Cat,
3. Male-Cat-Female

With `df.temp.str.count(i)`, it is showing Male-Cat count as `'2'`, which when search in data that is only `'1'`, wrongly including substring of third category.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should post some data, along with a better description of what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765927/2901002):

```
df['count'] = df.temp.str.count(r'(?<!\S)Male-Cat(?!\S)')
print (df)

                                           temp  count
0  Male-Cat Female-Cat Male-Cat-Female Male-Cat      2
1                               Male-Cat-Female      0
2                                      Male-Cat      1
3             Male-Cat Male-Cat Male-Cat-Female      2
4                    Male-Cat Male-Cat Male-Cat      3
```