# Cannot extract all words using word or whitespace boundary with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, findall, boundary

I need extract double `Male-Cat`:

```
a = "Male-Cat Male-Cat Male-Cat-Female"
b = re.findall(r'(?:\s|^)Male-Cat(?:\s|$)', a)
print (b)
['Male-Cat ']

c = re.findall(r'\bMale-Cat\b', a)
print (c)
['Male-Cat', 'Male-Cat', 'Male-Cat']
```

I need extract tree times `Male-Cat`:

```
a = "Male-Cat Male-Cat Male-Cat"
b = re.findall(r'(?:\s|^)Male-Cat(?:\s|$)', a)
print (b)
['Male-Cat ', ' Male-Cat']

c = re.findall(r'\bMale-Cat\b', a)
print (c)
['Male-Cat', 'Male-Cat', 'Male-Cat']
```

Another strings which are parsed correctly by first way:

```
a = 'Male-Cat Female-Cat Male-Cat-Female Male-Cat'
a = 'Male-Cat-Female'
a = 'Male-Cat'
```

Something missing? Can you explain what is wrong and what is correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lookarounds to extract words inside whitespace boundaries:

```
r'(?<!\S)Male-Cat(?!\S)'
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UYVngF/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string must appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `Male-Cat` - the term to search for
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string must appear immediately to the right of the current location

Since `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` are zero-width assertions, the whitespace won't be consumed, and consecutive matches will get found.