# How to replace a string using a dictionary containing multiple values for a key in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary

I have dictionary with Word and its closest related words.

I want to replace the  related words in the string with original word.
Currently I am able replace words in the string which has only value per key ,I  am not able to replace strings for a Key has multiple values. 
How can this be done

**Example Input**

```
North Indian Restaurant
South India  Hotel
Mexican Restrant
Italian  Hotpot
Cafe Bar
Irish Pub
Maggiee Baar
Jacky Craft Beer
Bristo 1889
Bristo 188
Bristo 188.
```

**How dictionary is made**

```
y= list(word)
words = y
similar = [[item[0] for item in model.wv.most_similar(word) if item[1] > 0.7] for word in words]
similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame({'Orginal_Word': words, 'Related_Words': similar})
similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix[['Orginal_Word', 'Related_Words']]
```

Its 2 columns inside a dataframe with lists

```
Orginal_Word    Related_Words
[Indian]        [India,Ind,ind.]    
[Restaurant]    [Hotel,Restrant,Hotpot]   
[Pub]           [Bar,Baar, Beer]     
[1888]          [188, 188., 18]
```

**Dictionary**

```
similarity_matrix.set_index('Orginal_Word')['Related_Words'].to_dict()

{'Indian ': 'India, Ind, ind.',
 'Restaurant': 'Hotel, Restrant, Hotpot',
 'Pub': 'Bar, Baar, Beer'
 '1888': '188, 188., 18'}
```

**Expected Output**

```
North Indian Restaurant
South India  Restaurant
Mexican Restaurant
Italian  Restaurant
Cafe Pub
Irish Pub
Maggiee Pub
Jacky Craft Pub
Bristo 1888
Bristo 1888
Bristo 1888
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by new dict with `regex` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765927/2901002):

```
d = {'Indian': 'India, Ind, ind.',
 'Restaurant': 'Hotel, Restrant, Hotpot',
 'Pub': 'Bar, Baar, Beer',
 '1888': '188, 188., 18'}

d1 = {r'(?<!\S)'+ k.strip() + r'(?!\S)':k1 for k1, v1 in d.items() for k in v1.split(',')}

df['col'] = df['col'].replace(d1, regex=True)
print (df)
                        col
0   North Indian Restaurant
1   South Indian Restaurant
2        Mexican Restaurant
3       Italian  Restaurant
4                  Cafe Pub
5                 Irish Pub
6               Maggiee Pub
7           Jacky Craft Pub
8               Bristo 1888
9               Bristo 1888
10              Bristo 1888
```

EDIT (Function for the above code):

```
def replace_words(d, col):
    d1={r'(?<!\S)'+ k.strip() + r'(?!\S)':k1 for k1, v1 in d.items() for k in v1.split(',')}
    df[col] = df[col].replace(d1, regex=True)
    return df[col]

df['col'] = replace_words(d, 'col')
```

EDIT1:

If get errors like:

> regex error- missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 7

is necessary escape regex values in keys:

```
import re

def replace_words(d, col):
    d1={r'(?<!\S)'+ re.escape(k.strip()) + r'(?!\S)':k1 for k1, v1 in d.items() for k in v1.split(',')}
    df[col] = df[col].replace(d1, regex=True)
    return df[col]

df['col'] = replace_words(d, 'col')
```

Comment: This will replace multiple times, dict is fine but how to replace once if expected

Comment: Nice with boundaries. Still need a bit more proper answer for last row. You can make it

Comment: @Dark,Updated the question . Its  basically 2 columns inside a dataframe with lists

Comment: @Rahulrajan - words for replace are always last?

Comment: @jezrael, Its should Bristo 188. should be Bristo 1888. Currently its coming 1888.

Comment: @jezrael, Its worked .Really helpful. I think you can make it a function so that it can used in all scenarios .

Comment: Function? Can you explain more? What are inputs of function?

Comment: @jezrael,to answer your question, words for replacement are not always last. they can be anywere

Comment: @jezrael  Abt the Function, The string to be replaced is a column in a dataframe and the words mappings are present in the dictionary. Whenever we want to replace  the string we just call the `apply function`

Comment: @jezrael, what does di mean in `def replace_words(di, col):`

Comment: @Rahulrajan - it is dictionary d, only I want change name for test. But if want change `di` to `d`