# Counting the occurrences of a substring in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, count

In my program I'm using `count=strr2.lower().count("ieee")` to calculate the number of occurrences in the following string,

> "i love ieee and ieeextream is the best coding competition ever"

In here it counts "*ieeextream*" is also as one occurrence which is not my expected result. The expected output is `count=1`

So are there any method to check only for "ieee" word or can we change the same code with different implementation? Thanks for your time

Comment: Its working as expected. `ieeextream` also contains `ieee`. Hence its counted.

Comment: `which is not my expected result` Why? Are you trying to check how many times `'ieee'` word appears, not as substring?

Comment: Hello @Mayank, but I'm expecting only ieee as one occurrence. so are there any method to get my expected output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764842/1374644

Comment: What is the expected count for `aa` in `aaa`? 0, 1, or 2 times?

Comment: @tobias_k 0 sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to find the sub-string as a whole word present in the original string, then I guess, this is what you need :

```
count=strr2.lower().split().count("ieee")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count only whole words, you can use a regular expression, wrapping the word to be found in word-boundary characters `\b`. This will also work if the word is surrounded by punctuation.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "i love IEEE, and ieeextream is the best coding competition ever"
>>> len(re.findall(r"\bieee\b", s.lower()))
1
```